# How I can find the value of the href in the JStree contextmenu attribute of child of li

Tags: object, contextmenu, jstree

I have a code like:

```
<li class="menu_li1" id="Id1"><a
href="../items/item1.php">Item1</a>
</li>
```

And would like add contextmenu.

It works, also I can receive some attribute of `<li>`

```
action: function (obj) {alert("rename");
alert(obj.attr('class'));
```

but I don't know how I can find value of `href`?

Comment: Did you try obj.attributes.href? Without looking at code, I would suggest you use Firebug and add a breakpoint in your javascript so you can inspect the obj variable